# Run python program within a JS file

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, function, api

I have a website where I can execute search queries. Afterwards, a search request over an API is generated, where the search query is saved in a variable called `query`:

```
    const { query, ...optionsFromState } = adaptRequest({
  ...state,
  ...(current !== undefined && { current }),
  ...(filters !== undefined && { filters }),
  ...(resultsPerPage !== undefined && { resultsPerPage }),
  ...(sortDirection !== undefined && { sortDirection }),
  ...(sortField !== undefined && { sortField })
});
```

Now, I want to use query and transform it with a python script. Let's say the script is called `transformation.py` and consists of a function, that takes the query and sends it to a neural network, which will result in some output. To simplify it, let's say inside the python script is a function, that produces `output = function(query)`. I then want to take that output and give it to some variable `output` within my original .js file. To conclude, I want to do something like this within my .js file:

```
send query as function parameter to transformation.py
output = output from transformation.py
```

How would I do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is the python code running on a server somewhere?

Comment: it is running on my local machine

Comment: Javascript in a browser can't call python on a local computer. Unless I am misunderstanding the website. Besides, how would you know if a user to the website has the python code to run?

Comment: sorry I should have added, the website is also run at my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Just like running a python script with the command line in the shell and checking the results with stdout, you can run the python script in nodejs using the exec() function.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec(`python transformation.py ${query}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`); // The output of transformation.py is displayed.
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```